# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION on line 56

Tags: php, function, execution

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in /home1/pgcomp77/public_html/svcsite/newtrial/new-dashboard/lib/smartui/class.smartutil.php on line 56

I am getting this error in page during execution time. Please help me

My code is

```
 public static function _get_property_value_func() {
              return function ($prop , $prop_methods) { // --> LINE 56
              $prop_string = "";
                if (SmartUtil::is_closure($prop)) {
                    return isset($prop_methods["if_closure"]) ? $prop_methods["if_closure"]($prop) : $prop($prop);
                } else if (is_array($prop) || is_object($prop)) {
                    if (is_object($prop)) 
                        $prop = SmartUtil::object_to_array($prop);
                    return isset($prop_methods["if_array"]) ? $prop_methods["if_array"]($prop) : $prop;
                } else {
                    return isset($prop_methods["if_other"]) ? $prop_methods["if_other"]($prop) : $prop;
                }
            };


        }
```

This code is running on localhost but not on server. Please help me someone

Comment: This is probably due to an old PHP version. Have you tried updating?

Comment: what version of PHP are you running? `closures` is available since PHP 5.3 and newer.

Comment: what's the php version of your server?

Answer (score 1):

The PHP Version on the server is most likely < 5.3. Anonymous functions are available since PHP 5.3.0.
Source: http://php.net/manual/de/functions.anonymous.php

Comment: then how i can run this code

Comment: The PHP System Default Version is 5.4